# how to pass variables inside a <href> tag in the google map's infoWindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

The sample_id shows in the infoWidow but how can it be passed inside the href tag?

```
(function (marker, sample) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseover", function (e) {
    infoWindow.setContent(sample.id+ ' - ' + sample.name + '</br>' + 
    '<a href="SampleDetail.aspx?sample_id="'+ sample.id + '> Detail...</a>' );
    infoWindow.open(map, marker); 
    });
})(marker, sample);
```

Comment: I think `'<a href="SampleDetail.aspx?sample_id='+ sample.id + '"> Detail...</a>'`

Comment: sorry, the infoWindow disappears with this

Comment: What do you see when you `console.log(sample.id)`? You need to add it in that function, open the developer tools and in the console tag you should be able to see the value. Please let me know what that value is

Comment: the value is an integer. As you can see sample.id twice in the code. The first one shows up correctly:        infoWindow.setContent(sample.id+ ' - ' + sample.name + '</br>' + 
    '<a href="SampleDetail.aspx?sample_id="'+ sample.id + '> Detail...</a>' );

Comment: And what's the value of `sample.name`? maybe it breaks the HTML structure?

Comment: is a string like names of places. it displays correctly in my original code

Comment: I see. Well sorry but i'm out of ideas, the only suggestion is to try and inspect the element, and try to figure out the issue. You should also try `console.log(<all the content inside infoWindow.setContent>)` and I hope you find an answer (I didn't downvote BTW)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have problem with mismatched string quotes:

```
 infoWindow.setContent(sample.id+ ' - ' + sample.name + '</br>' + 
'<a href="SampleDetail.aspx?sample_id="'+ sample.id + '> Detail...</a>' );
                                      ^
                                      |
                                     this
infoWindow.setContent(sample.id+ ' - ' + sample.name + '</br>' + 
'<a href="SampleDetail.aspx?sample_id='+ sample.id + '"> Detail...</a>' );
                                                      ^
                                                      |
                                         should be here
```

This works:

```
(function(marker, sample) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseover", function(e) {
      infoWindow.setContent(sample.id + ' - ' + sample.name + '</br>' +
        '<a href="SampleDetail.aspx?sample_id=' + sample.id + '"> Detail...</a>');
      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
  })(marker, sample);
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/be05jqL5/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    map: map
  });
  var sample = {
    id: 5,
    name: "frank"
  };
  (function(marker, sample) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseover", function(e) {
      infoWindow.setContent(sample.id + ' - ' + sample.name + '</br>' +
        '<a href="SampleDetail.aspx?sample_id=' + sample.id + '"> Detail...</a>');
      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
  })(marker, sample);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: You have got to be kidding me, that was what I posted in the comments and the OP dismissed my solution (Unless I missed something else). Well, at least you managed to explain it better :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
"<a href='SampleDetail.aspx?sample_id=" + sample.id + "'> Detail...</a>"
```

Comment: tried it and it doesn't work. The infowindow disappears entirely.

Comment: Issue might be somewhere other than the <a> tag. You can try to console.log() your content to see if there's a problem in either sample.id or sample.name.

Comment: not familiar with console.log() but they do appear in infowindow correctly in my code.

Comment: console.log() will output the string you give has parameter to the browser console. In that same console you can see possible javascript errors. You can also use alert() to show that text on a alert window on your screen. sample.name can easily contain a character that html recognized has html and breaks the code inside the content of your infowindow.